# where is invalid type coming from in my code/df? x invalid 'type' (closure) of argument - Mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

[image]

I am trying to use mutate to get the percentages of behaviours accross time categories, however I keep getting this error.

> Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `n`. i `n = sum(count)`. x
> invalid 'type' (closure) of argument i The error occurred in group 1:
> Time = 23 19, PredictedBehaviorFull = Bait, Context = Present.

This is my current script

```r
S06Behav <- S06 %>%
  group_by(Time, PredictedBehaviorFull, Context) %>%
  summarise(count= n())

S06Proportions <- S06  %>%
  group_by(Time, PredictedBehaviorFull, Context) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(count)) %>%
  mutate(percentage = n / sum(n))
 
write.csv(S06Proportions, "S06Proportions.csv")

#Stacked bar graph
ggplot(
  S06Proportions,
  aes(
    fill=PredictedBehaviourFull,
    y=percentage,
    x=Time,
    levels=Context, position_dodge(preserve = "total")
  )) +
  geom_bar(
    position="fill", stat="identity", group = "Context") +
   facet_wrap(~ Context) +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8, angle = 66)) +
   labs(x= "Time", y= ("Percentage"))
```

I have also found that the script keeps changing the order of my "time" column which is just d h. This then messes up the stacked bar graph order making it non sequential. I am working with data accross multiple days and two context so having this order correct is important.

A sample of my data is https://pastebin.com/KE0xEzk7

EDIT
: the script is now running however there is an issue with how it is calculating the % as seen in the picture bellow. It is also still changing the order of my groups. Thank you for your help!

Comment: In the tidyverse, `count` is a function (although the error message uses the more precise term "closure".) The problem is that you haven't said what you want to count. Maybe you wanted the number of items in each group. Perhaps the `nrow` function or the `n` function was intended?

Comment: Since your edit changes the focus of your question you should consider posting a new question with your working code and the issue you are now encountering. Instead of posting a link to a pastebin ressource, please use `dput(head(S06))` to show the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By

```r
summarise(n = sum(count))
```

you are trying to sum up a column named `count`, which isn't present in your dataset. My guess is, you are trying to do

```r
S06 %>%
  count(Time, PredictedBehaviorFull, Context)
```

or

```r
S06Behav %>%
  group_by(Time, PredictedBehaviorFull, Context) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(count)) %>%
  mutate(percentage = n / sum(n))
```

since your newly created `S06Behav` contains a `count` column.

Comment: Thank you that script is running without the warning message however the out put isnt working properly.  I have edited the question to include an image of the output I am currently getting. It isn't assigning the percentages properly and is changing the order of my "time" column.